# How to combine multiple RewriteCond in one domain using Apache in Ubuntu?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, mod-rewrite, dns

I am struggling with htaccess and apache setting of my domain. I am using SSL so I have two virtual hosts `<VirtualHost *:80>` and `<VirtualHost *:443>` I am trying to combine these two conditions into one:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Which suppose to be redirecting any addresses like `test.domain.com` to `domain.com/test` if exists but also use HTTPS like this:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

My question is: How to combine these two into one file and where to use them? In `<VirtualHost *:80>` ?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 things to solve  -

1. Redirecting everything to https
2. passing subdomain as uri.

For point 1, in your *:80 virutal host add below -

```
Redirect permanent / https://mysite.example.com/
```

For point 2, in your *:443 virtual host add below for the url conversion

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: This does not really work ... it creates multiple root adresses like /www//www//www//www//www/ and I think there should be https in the second one? Also you removed to be always www, at the begining ...

Comment: I shared this as reference, haven't validated, but shared the approach. for your use case you need to make changes accordingly. For multiple addresses appending, you can set the rule to END

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a abc.conf file under 
/etc/apache2/sites-available/abc.conf and write this in that file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName abc.com
    ServerAlias www.abc.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/abc.com
    <Directory /var/www/abc.com>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/abc.com.error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/abc.com.log combined
        RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =abc.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName abc.com
    ServerAlias www.abc.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/abc.com
    <Directory /var/www/abc.com>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/abc.com.error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/abc.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/abc.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

after this you need to enable your .conf file by type

`sudo a2ensite abc.conf` and restart your apache 
and `a2dismod 000-default.conf` and restart again.

Comment: Hello, thank you but this does not make everything www. at the begining => abc.com has to be always www.abc.com. Also it does not convert x.abc.com to www.abc.coom/x Also did you mean a2dissite 000-default.conf ?

Comment: yes typo error a2dissite. Means you have a child domain do this add "Redirect permanent x.abc.com www.abc.coom/x" in that file